# Jquery chechboxTree and Cookie plugin - Problem with getting children

Tags: jquery, plugins, cookies

I'm using the checkboxTree plugin in relation with the cookie plugin for jquery.
My problem is, I'd like to set/unset all cookies of the children (from header) when a checkbox with class "header" was clicked.
How can I do that?
Here's my .js code:

```
 // When page has loaded, check each checkbox if it's checked (set cookie) or not (unset cookie)
 $(".tree input:checkbox").each(function(){
  var elementId = this.id;

  // Check if a cookie of the element exists
  if($.cookie(elementId)){
   // If so, change attribute to checked
   $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
  }else{
   // If not, change attribute to not checked
   $(this).attr("checked", "");
  }

 });

 $(".tree input:checkbox").change(function(){
  if($(this).attr("class") == "header"){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
    setCookie(this.id);
    // Set cookie for all children
   }else{
    unsetCookie(this.id);
    // Unset cookie for all children
   }
  }else{
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
    setCookie(this.id);
   }else{
    unsetCookie(this.id);
   }
  }
 });

 function setCookie(element){
  $.cookie(element, "checked");
 }

 function unsetCookie(element){
  $.cookie(element, null);
 }


    $('.tree').checkboxTree({
     onCheck: { 
         node: 'expand' 
        }, 
        onUncheck: { 
            node: 'collapse' 
        }, 
     collapseImage: '../media/images/icons/minus.png',
        expandImage: '../media/images/icons/plus.png'
    });
```

And here my html code:

```
   <div id="filterTree">
     <ul class="tree">
         <li><input type="checkbox" id="Human Ressources" class="header">Human Resources
             <ul>
                 <li><input type="checkbox" id="Finance">Finance
                 <li><input type="checkbox" id="Personnel">Personnel
                 <li><input type="checkbox" id="Post Office">Post Office
                 <li><input type="checkbox" id="House Service">House Service
                 <li><input type="checkbox" id="Reception">Reception
                </ul>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your error? And the last attribute of the object should not have a "," after it.

Comment: I don't get an error. Until here it's working fine, but I'd like to set/unset all children cookies when a header was clicked. 
"Set cookies for all children" there should be a function, which sets all the cookies for the children. And in "Unset cookie for all children" the same but unset and not set.

Comment: When header has changed to "checked" I'd like to add following cookies: Finance, Personnel, Post Office, House Service and Reception. When header has changed to "not checked" I'd like to remove those cookies.
But I don't know how can I get all children and set/unset for each children the cookie.
Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if($(this).attr("class") == "header"){
    //selects all input of the type checkbox that are within the ul li elements, each loops trough the list of those elements
    $(this).parents("ul.tree").find("ul li input:checkbox").each(function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")){  //if this item of the list is checked set a cookie, otherwise unset it.
        setCookie(this.id);
      }
      else {
        unsetCookie(this.id);
      }
    });
  }
```

And remove the "," on the end of

```
expandImage: '../media/images/icons/plus.png',
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.
Also I think you forgot the ");" after each function (I added them)?
When I click on the checkbox with class header all checkboxes are checked or not checked (comes from the checkboxTree plugin). When you refresh the site, the checkboxes aren't checked/not checked as before (that's why I used cookies to save the settings). Hope you can help me :) (I removed the ",").

Comment: Idd i forgot that. Fixed it now. You sure the functions for cookies works fine? It worked with 1 element?

Comment: :) It's working absolutely fine for one or more element. Only the "header function" doesn't work. I think (this).children("input:checkbox") doesn't get the element because I added an alert before the function but it only returns undefinied:
alert($(this).children("input:checkbox").attr("id"));

Comment: I think i understand you now. Fixed the code. It should remember all childs of header now. The undifinied is probably because that selector reterns a list of elements. A list doesnt have the attribute id. Try `alert($(this).children("input:checkbox").size());` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but it still doesn't work. When I put an  alert($(this).children("input:checkbox").size()); in front of the each function, it returns me always 0. (You've got a mistake in your code. "}" should be after "});")

Comment: Yeah, I was obvious sleeping when I was looping trough the children of an input element. Fixed it now with a parent selector.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work. The return of alert($(this).parent("ul.tree").children("input:checkbox").size()); is also still 0. Why doesn't it recognize the children elements...

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine! Also when I add some other functions :)